# Flutter Draggable and ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to create a list, which should be capable of reordering within but also I should be able to delete an item if dragged to a particular drag target. Right now I have incorporated these two functionalities in two different screens. One using ReorderabelListView and the other using Draggable. Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It seems that `Draggable` widgets get ignored when inside a `ReorderableListView`. 

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by using [reorderables plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables)

```dart
ReorderableColumn(
  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {

  },
  children: someList.map((item) {
    final index = someList.indexOf(item);

    return Dismissible(
      key: ObjectKey(item),
      onDismissed: (direction) {

      },
      background: Container(color: Colors.red),
      child: Container(),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```