# Draggable and ReorderableListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In addition to reordering the elements, I want to be able to delete them when I drag them to the trash

[Flutter Draggable and ReorderableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594995/flutter-draggable-and-reorderablelistview)

I want to rearrange A, B, and C by drag and drop and delete them.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0NNn.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Draggable** Widget to this purpose. When dragging completed remove the specific item from the list. Check below site for more details.

[**Draggable** widget details](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Certainly it can be removed by using the Draggable class. But I don't know how to rearrange them while dragging.  I will try to implement it using the onWillAccept property.